# Checking if 5 secs has elapsed

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.7

I have this code (below) which detects a if a player is in a zone (using `pygame`) and check if they have been in the zone for 5 secs and print done if the player. If the player leaves the zone it should do nothing.

```
if deletezone.colliderect(plyr):
   wait_time = 5000  # How long to wait (in milliseconds).
   already_inzone = True
   wait_time -= 60     # Decrease the time
   if wait_time <= 0 and already_inzone:   # If the time has got to 0
     print("done")
else:
   already_inzone = False
```

However, it does not print `"done"` and I do not get an error. Can anyone spot what I've done wrong please?

Comment: Have you tried printing something in the `else` block?

Comment: In the example you provided, how exactly do you expect that `wait_time` will ever be `<= 0`?

Comment: @esqew `wait_time -= 60`?

Comment: Even though `5000 - 60` is `4940`?

Comment: your `wait_time` will be `5000-60` and then it wont decrement further, as you dont have any code to do that

Comment: You reset `wait_time` every time you detect that the player is in the zone.

Comment: @esqew oh XD thanks

Answer (score 0):

`wait_time` is being reset to 5000 every time it detects the player in the zone.